# T-SQL Recursive with two initial statements

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion

I don't have idea how to write this recursive in SQL. How handle with CTE when I have two initial assumptions?
Below easy example:

- a1 = 2
- a2 = 3
- an = a(n-1)*a(n-2)

I tried write something like below but unfortunately I don't know how handle with this:

```
with recur(n,results) as
(
select 1,2
union all
select 2,3
union all
select 
/*how to write this pattern?*/
where n<
)

select * from recur
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: am no expert in maths..Can you explain the logic ? what is the value of `a` ?

Comment: It' example of arithmetic progression.firs value of this progression is equal 2, second is equal 3, every another its equal of value multiplied by previouse two

Comment: Gotcha.. Which version of sql server you are using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to generate the Fibonacci numbers using a recursive CTE.

Try something like this:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 1 AS N, 2 AS A, 3 AS B
    UNION ALL
    SELECT N+1 AS N, B AS A, A+B AS B
    FROM CTE
    WHERE N<10
)
SELECT A FROM CTE
```

Comment: @PrzemekKaczmarek, btw if you're interested in a specific number in the Fibonacci sequence, you can use the following formula inline (given the position in the sequence) without recursing: `ROUND(POWER((1 + SQRT(5)) / 2, (sequence_number + 1)) / SQRT(5), 0)`